# Insert and delete on focus of loop widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

how can i do this? this works but only with the last ScrolledText, i need it to work with the specific ScrolledText, been playing with name  but cant seem to get it to work.

Any ideas?

```
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))




for x in range(6):
    kiblogbn = ScrolledText(root, name="frm_"+x, width=25, height=30, border=2, relief="solid")
    kiblogbn.grid(column=x, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=25, sticky="W")

    kiblogbn.insert("1.0", 'Copy logs here.')
    kiblogbn.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda _: kiblogbn.delete('1.0', 'end'))
    kiblogbn.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda _: kiblogbn.insert("1.0", "Copy logs here." if str(kiblogbn.get("1.0", "end")) == "\n" else ""))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code in the question only has a single `ScrolledText` widget. It's hard to know what you mean by "the last ScrolledText". Please create a working [mcve].

Comment: done, please see the post update

Comment: Put the `kiblogbn` in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the two lines:

```py
kiblogbn.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda _: kiblogbn.delete('1.0', 'end'))
kiblogbn.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda _: kiblogbn.insert("1.0", "Copy logs here." if str(kiblogbn.get("1.0", "end")) == "\n" else ""))
```

to

```
kiblogbn.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: e.widget.delete('1.0', 'end'))
kiblogbn.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e: e.widget.insert("1.0", "Copy logs here." if str(e.widget.get("1.0", "end")) == "\n" else ""))
```

Also `name="frm_"+x` will raise error because `x` is integer.  Change it to `name="frm_"+str(x)`.

---

Update: delete content when focus out only if the content is the same as the placeholder:

```py
PLACEHOLDER = 'Copy logs here.'

for x in range(6):
    kiblogbn = ScrolledText(root, name="frm_"+str(x), width=25, height=30, border=2, relief="solid")
    kiblogbn.grid(column=x, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=25, sticky="W")

    kiblogbn.insert("1.0", PLACEHOLDER)
    kiblogbn.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: e.widget.delete("1.0", "end-1c") if e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c") == PLACEHOLDER else None)
    kiblogbn.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e: e.widget.insert("1.0", PLACEHOLDER if e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c") == "" else ""))
```

Recommend to use functions instead of lambdas for better readability.

Comment: craizy thing that i havent thought before, after we enter text, it desapear on focus out :s how do i fix that?

Comment: another thing, how can i call a function in focus out?             kiblogbn.bind("<FocusOut>",lambda e: e.widget.insert("1.0", PLACEHOLDER if e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c") == "" else "" ,lambda e,widget:checkval(e,widget,y, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5)))